# How to Make Tkinter Canvas Transparent

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I am trying to overlay different canvas geometries on top of an image. However, my problem is that the canvas itself has a color that blocks most of the image. How can I make this canvas transparent, so that only the geometries that I draw are visible? Here is my code in case my explanation did not suffice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Infrared Camera Interface")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)



class MyApp:
  def __init__(self, parent):


    #Set the dimensions of the window
    parent.minsize(width=600, height=600)
    parent.maxsize(width=600, height=600)


    #Prepare the image object being loaded into the stream camera
    self.imgName = 'Dish.png'
    self.img = Image.open(self.imgName)
    self.img = self.img.resize((560, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS)     

    #Display the image onto the stream
    self.displayimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    self.imglabel = Label(root, image=self.displayimg).place(x=0, y= 0)


    self.C = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="white", height=560, width=450)

    coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
    arc = self.C.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=150, fill="red")

    self.C.pack()

myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: as I know you can make canvas transparent. But I don't understand `canvas ... blocks most of the image`. What do you try to do ? What do you expect ?

Comment: Hi, I uploaded an image of the current program. As you can see, the white color of the canvas covers most of the image. I just want the red geometry that is displayed above.

Comment: now I see: you use label to keep image and canvas to add object. Put image on canvas `canvas.create_image()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can make canvas transparent.

But you can draw image directly on canvas: [canvas.create_images()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.